# Bash variable math expansion not working with printf

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get a formatted number that increments every time through a while loop.

I've got `fnum=$(printf "%03d" $((++num)) )` but the number doesn't increment. `fnum` is "000" and remains at that.

Of course `num=$((++num)) ; fnum=$(printf "%03d" $num)` works but I'm wondering why the first one doesn't increment the number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need comamnd-substitution(`$(..)`) in the first place to store the output of `printf` use the `-v` option to store it in a variable

```
printf -v fnum "%03d" $((++num))
```

Also the `num` variable is updated in a sub-shell, `$(..)` runs the command inside in a separate shell. The value of `num` incremented will *never* be reflected back in the parent shell.

Comment: :facepalm: Of course it's in a sub-shell. Thank you for the `-v` tip as well.

Comment: @TonyWilliams: It happens ;)

Answer (score 2):

With:

```
$(printf "%03d" $((++num)))
```

the command inside `$()` is run in a *sub-shell* so changes to the `num` variable in there are not carried back to the parent shell.

With the working version, `num=$((++num))` is executed in the context of the *current* shell, so `num` is modified.

Of course, it makes little sense to assign back to `num` since the side-effect of `++` is changing `num` anyway, so you can just do something like:

```
((++num)) ; fnum=$(printf "%03d" $num)
```

And you can totally *avoid* starting a sub-shell and just use internal `bash` stuff, which will make a large difference if you need to do this a lot<sup>(a)</sup>:

```
((++num)) ; fnum=000${num} ; fnum=${fnum: -3} ; doSomethingWith ${fnum}
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> As seen in the following script:

```
rm -f qq[12]

time (
    var=0
    while [[ ${var} -lt 99999 ]] ; do
        ((++var))
        svar=$(printf "%05d" ${var})
        echo ${svar}
    done
) >>qq1

time (
    var=0
    while [[ ${var} -lt 99999 ]] ; do
        ((++var))
        svar=00000${var}
        svar=${svar: -5}
        echo ${svar}
    done
) >>qq2
```

The first snippet takes a little over nine seconds CPU time (user+system) to run, the second completes in about a second (the difference is even *more* pronounced if you measure wall clock time, since many copies of "printf in a subshell" need to be started):

```
real  0m30.875s
user  0m0.320s
sys   0m9.144s

real  0m1.008s
user  0m0.924s
sys   0m0.080s
```

Comment: I am also fan of `svar=00000${var};
        svar=${svar: -5}` mechanism. There is a catch though. For negative values, it becomes weird. If the number is guaranteed to be positive, then there is no issue.